# How do a get a clean import namespace for a package in python?

Tags: python

I'm sure this is trivial to do, but I can't figure it out.

Directory structure:

```
mylib/__init__.py
mylib/MyClass.py
```

**init**.py reads:

```
import MyClass
__all__ = [MyClass]
```

MyClass.py:

```
class MyClass(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

I have to create instances of MyClass using mylib.MyClass.MyClass(), when I want it to be mylib.MyClass()

I thought that to get this to work I have to put **all** = [MyClass.MyClass], but that didn't work.

How do you get this to work?

NB. I understand what is happening here; the file itself is a namespace and you could for example say, have multiple classes in a single file. However, I only have one class in each .py file, so I don't want that level of detail.

ie. 
I have this:

```
>>> import mylib
>>> tmp = mylib.MyClass.MyClass()
```

I want this:

```
>>> import mylib
>>> tmp = mylib.MyClass()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `__init__.py`, nstead of `import MyClass` try `from MyClass import MyClass`.

The former command imports the module's name into your namespace; the second imports a symbol *from* the module (in this case, the name of a class) into your namespace.

Also, `__all__` should be a list of *names,* i.e., strings, not references.

Generally, there is not any advantage in Python to dividing up your classes one to a file, and some mild disadvantages to doing so. Usually all your classes would be in a single file, and users would already be able to access your class as `mylib.MyClass`.